# How can I uninstall palettes?

Tags: palettes, installation

I am a first-time user pf *Mathematica* (V10). I know it's easy to install palettes, but uninstalling them drives me crazy. I want to delete one. Who can help me to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: IIRC, evaluate `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "Palettes"}]`, note location, exit MMA, go there and move folder(s) for palette.

Comment: It's one of my little annoyances too. Rasher's solution is indeed what you generally have to do, but it's kind of silly that deinstallation is so much more cumbersome than installation.

Comment: Unfortunately there can be many locations where the palette is installed.  The first location to check is the one mentioned by rasher, but it may be somewhere else.  Can you tell us which palette you are having trouble with please?

Comment: You can check where palettes are stored with `Options[$FrontEnd, PalettePath]` or just look in Global Options > File Locations > Palette Path.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a bare bones tool to remove a palette and place it in a new directory. You can modify to delete the file entirely if you wish. You can modify the sources. There is an internal FE command to update the palette menu but I do not have that. You'll have to restart Mathematica.

```
DynamicModule[{new, 
  source1 = 
   FileNameJoin[{$BaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
     "Palettes"}], 
  source2 = 
   FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
     "Palettes"}], 
  source3 = 
   FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "*", "FrontEnd", 
     "Palettes"}], menu, palette},

 new = FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "Uninstalled Palettes"}];
 If[! DirectoryQ[new],
  CreateDirectory[new]
  ];

 menu = # -> Composition[Last, FileNameSplit][#] & /@ 
   FileNames["*nb", {source1, source2, source3}];

 Dynamic[
  If[menu =!= {},
   Row[{
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[palette], menu], Spacer[10],

     Button["Remove Palette",
      CopyFile[palette, 
       FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "Uninstalled Palettes", 
         Composition[Last, FileNameSplit][palette]}]];
      DeleteFile[palette]
      ]
     }],
   "No Palettes Found"
   ],
  TrackedSymbols :> {menu}]

 ]
```

[image]

...and you could of course make this into a palette for easy access.

Answer (score 4):

Open the folder:

```mathematica
SystemOpen[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "Palettes"}]]
```

and delete the palettes you want.

If you do not find the palette you want to remove, try `$UserBaseDirectory` or `$InstallationDirectory`.